# How to insert cautionary key signature before repeat mark using Sibelius 7

Tags: software, key-signatures, repeats, sibelius

I'm arranging wind parts for the following song (excerpt below). This is the end of a repeated section that starts in D major and changes to F major halfway through. So, the repeat mark at the end of the section, (in the first and second time bars) sends the player back to D major. Therefore I need a cautionary D major key signature (as written in the music already).

So, how do I get these cautionary D major key signatures, using Sibelius 7, without changing the key of the *following* bars? Or would it just be easiest to do this with symbols in each of the parts? (Which isn't ideal…)

[image]

Comment: I don't know anything about Sibelius but have you tried this link? The answers appear to be good. http://www.sibelius.com/cgi-bin/helpcenter/chat/chat.pl?com=thread&start=624872&groupid=3&&guest=1

Comment: Looks good - I can't try it at the moment, as I'm doing something else. If it does work, you should put the link in an answer and I can let you have the bounty… I'll get back to you… You could put the link in an answer anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link might be useful:
[Sib. 7.1.3: Cautionary key signature immediately before end repeat barline?](http://www.sibelius.com/cgi-bin/helpcenter/chat/chat.pl?com=thread&start=624872&groupid=3&&guest=1)
I'll paste an answer here anyway. It's also possible to ask your question on that forum I think, people over there might be more knowledgeable about this.

A sample answer:

> Re: Sib. 7.1.3: Cautionary key signature immediately before end repeat barline?
> Posted by Richard Hatton - 20 Feb 02:54PM
>
> It can be done.
>
> 1. Have your repeat barline as usual and put in the key change (which will end up after the barline.
> 2. click on the key sigature on one of the staves and drag it back to before the barline.
> 3. Move the barline to the end of the system (either by dragging or by using the inspector. (if using the inspector I found an "X" value of -1.5 was about right)
> 4. Tidy up the key signature position relative to the barline by dragging.
>
> Note you can move the key signatures using the inspector but you need to select all of them first, I found it easier to drag! Also do the final positioning in a Transposing score else you could have some key signatures runninginto the repeat barline.
>
> --
> Richard Hatton
> Sibelius 7.1.3 ,Photoscore Ult. 7.0.2; Windows 7 64 bit; quad core i7, 16GB ram; core I5, 8 GB ram also with Sibelius 6.2 and Photoscore 6.1.

Comment: Yesterday I started writing an answer suggesting you drag the key signature left after you've inserted it. I didn't post the answer when I realised that although the score looks OK, it doesn't play back correctly. Sibelius places key changes at the beginning of a bar, rather than a cautionary at the end of a previous bar. So I think that the engraving construct that's been requested may not strictly be required. But I couldn't find any engraving articles that categorically state how this music example should look.

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS thanks for your advice. I kind of took your approach in the end anyway. When copying and arranging I'm not too fussed about playback.

Answer (score 2):

The solution @Sazid_violin linked to 90% solves this problem, so I've awarded the bounty.

However, to get the cautionary natural on the D major key signature in the *second* time bar, I had to put an F major key signature in and hide it (shift-cmd-H). (BTW, I decided not to have a third time bar after all, so there is a double bar-line instead of a repeat mark, but I still needed to go into D major, so needed the same solution.) See below:

[image]

Just thought I'd post this here, in case anybody else has the same problem. I haven't "answered" the question...